# Java remote debugging on linux target using Eclipse or otherwise

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging

Can anyone tell me a good approach to remote debugging Java on linux targets?

What I'm after is some method to build my Java project, deploy to target and then debug on the target.
I know java can debug on target by starting the running JAR with debug flags 
e.g.

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y suspend=y -jar stockTradingGUI.jar
```

But I don't know how to trigger the deployment of built JAR to the target and running in debug mode through Eclipse.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: are you running the code on some server (e.g. tomcat) or is it a standalone executable JAR?

Comment: If you do not have an adapter helping you, you build locally, copy to the target, optionally restart the remote JVM and then attach.  It is usually rather tedious - so if at all possible see if you can change your workflow to _develop_ on a locally running server-instance, and only _test_ on the remote

Comment: Pat - I'm running a standalone executable JAR

Comment: Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen - Yes, this is my workflow (local build, copy to target, start build in debug mode and attach). I'm using GPIO on a Raspberry PI which is why I can't completely developed locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With *Eclipse* itself, one generally wouldn't try to do the deployment of the built JAR to the target and have it run in debug mode. Instead, one would start the remote debugging session in *Eclipse* after having deployed the newly built jar and started it with the various debug/suspend flags to allow you to remotely connect to it.

There are a variety methods of doing the deploy.

The most straightforward would be to simply do a regular built in *Eclipse* (or at the command line via *ant* or using whatever build tool you are using), manually *scp* the jar over to the remote location, and *ssh* into the box and start the app up using the necessary commands.

Another option is to use a deployment framework such as *fabric* (written in *Python*) which will do the build, *scp* it over to your remote location, and then run whatever commands you need to run in order to get that up and running (i.e. first stopping an existing *Tomcat* instance, etc. or whatever the case may be). You can have different environments setup in the *fabfile*, such as *debug* and *prod*, so you can deploy it in *debug* mode for cases like you are looking for now, and then in *prod* mode it deploys normally and just runs.

If you are using *Gradle*, it has some tools such as *Cargo* that can help with remote deployments, or for simpler use cases, using the *ssh* plugin and managing things more directly (see http://java.dzone.com/articles/replace-your-scripts-gradle for more details).

**Edit in response to comment from OP:**

I've not used *Remote System Explorer* myself, but it appears to be [extensible](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Frse_int_architecture.html) to some extent (see the Service and Subsystem layers), although fundamentally it still seems to be UI-focused.

For this sort of use case I would recommend giving *Gradle* another look, as it's focused on building, is very extensible, and can be integrated into *Eclipse* or run completely on the command line.

Comment: I was hoping that there would be some sort of Eclipse plugin that could handle the deployment after build but your idea of Gradle or Fabric might do the trick.

Do you know if something like the Eclipse Remote System Explorer is scriptable at all?